# VBA looping error

Tags: vba, excel, loops

I am relatively new to writing VBA in Excel. In an Excel worksheet I have events occuring in a single row across a number of columns.  These events are signified just by their color (other than that they are blank cells). Imagine having cells A1 through G1 colored red and H1 through V1 colored blue.

I am trying to write a sub that tells me when a cell changes color.  With my current code, in text below, Excel stops responding and error code " run-time error '-2147417848 (80010108)' " pops up.  I am unsure of where the problem is occuring.

```
Sub colorReader()

    Set a = ActiveCell

    Range("C8").Select

    Dim cellColor As String
    cellColor = ActiveCell.Interior.Color
    MsgBox (cellColor)

    Do While cellColor = "13408767"
        a = ActiveCell.Offset(, 1)
        If cellColor <> "13408767" Then
            MsgBox ("end color")
        End If
    Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `ActiveCell` is never changing. I imagine you want to loop through the cells and just test if the cell color you find is different than the cell color of the cell in the same row but just one column over. Like so

```
for i= 3 to 100 'or whatever your last column number happens to be
    'This tests to see if the interior color of a cell is different from
    'the on in the same row but the next column over
    if cells(8, i).Interior.ColorIndex <> cells(8, i+1).Interior.ColorIndex then
        MsgBox("color changes")
    end if
next i
```

I'm guessing you will want to replace `MsgBox("color changes")` with something useful that tells you where the color change takes place, like `MsgBox("Column " & i + 1 & " had a change of color from the column immediately to the left of it.")`.

Comment: Thank you! And yes I am going to change the MsgBox, I was just using that as a checkpoint to make sure the code was working properly before I continued on.

Answer (score 0):

Your cell referencing could do with a little work, normally it's considered bad to .select something.  You also need to move the range, in the code below the range a is moved each time.  Try this:

```
Sub colorReader()
dim a as range
Set a = activeworksheet.Range("C8")


Dim cellColor As String
cellColor = ActiveCell.Interior.Color
MsgBox (cellColor)

Do While cellColor = "13408767"
    a = a.Offset(, 1)
    If cellColor <> "13408767" Then
        MsgBox ("end color")
    End If
Loop
End Sub
```